# Android: Camera.open() does not work in onResume() method

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an app where I open the camera at `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        openCamera();
        ....
}


public void openCamera() {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            Log.d(CAMERA, "Camre opened");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e(CAMERA, "Cannot open camera", exception);
        }
    }
```

openCamera() method works fine if I don't call it in `onResume()` method, but within `onResume()` method it gives me the following exception:

```
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753): Cannot open camera
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:302)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:279)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at buet.threebyzero.autoSecuritySystem.Capture.openCamera(Capture.java:46)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at buet.threebyzero.autoSecuritySystem.Capture.onResume(Capture.java:55)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-15 14:50:33.999: E/camera(1753):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:** Problem partially solved after restarting the emulator and overriding `onPause()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(camera != null)
            camera.release();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but make sure you `release` the camera everytime when your Activity goes in background.

Comment: I get this exception everytime `onResume()` is called, even after `onCreate()`.